# CS50 PSET4 filter-more : edges() function (Filtering Image to some extent , but not matching with the answer.)

Tags: c, image-processing, cs50, edge-detection, sobel

Link to the problem (edges part only) [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/filter/more/).

In this code I am using sobel operator to identify the edged in a bmp image.

I have tried various different things, the code compiles correctly (there is no error), and also the output image obtained shows the edges of the pixels , it looks like the sobel filter is applied correctly , but when I check my code , it is not matching with the answer.
Please help me find the error in my code which is responsible for the same.
Thanks.

Here is the main code of the function:

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    // Array for storing corresponding gx values of the pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE(*gx)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (gx == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store blur pixels.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Array for storing corresponding gy values of the pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE(*gy)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (gy == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store blur pixels.\n");
        return;
    }


    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            Gx(row, col, height, width, image, gx);
            Gy(row, col, height, width, image, gy);
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            image[row][col].rgbtBlue = r_sqrt_sum(gx[row][col].rgbtBlue, gy[row][col].rgbtBlue);
            image[row][col].rgbtGreen = r_sqrt_sum(gx[row][col].rgbtGreen, gy[row][col].rgbtGreen);
            image[row][col].rgbtRed = r_sqrt_sum(gx[row][col].rgbtRed, gy[row][col].rgbtRed);

        }
    }

    free(gx);
    free(gy);
    return;
}
```

Declaration of gx and gy:

```
void Gx(int row, int col, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE matrix[height][width], RGBTRIPLE new_matrix[height][width])
// This function will return Gx value of a given pixel.
{
    float Blue = 0;
    float Green = 0;
    float Red = 0;

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
        {
            // for rows and columns out of range.
            if ((i + row) < 0 || (i + row >= height) || (j + col) < 0 || (j + col >= width))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // for (-1,-1) and (1,-1)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == -1) || (i == 1 && j == -1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -1;
            }

            // for (0,-1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == -1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -2;
            }

            // for (-1, 0) , (0, 0), (1, 0)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 1 && j == 0))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 0;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 0;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 0;
            }

            // for (0, 1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 2;
            }

            // for (-1,1) and (1,1)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == 1) || (i == 1 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 1;
            }
        }
    }

    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtBlue = fabsf(Blue);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtGreen = fabsf(Green);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtRed = fabsf(Red);
}


void Gy(int row, int col, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE matrix[height][width], RGBTRIPLE new_matrix[height][width])
// This function will return Gy value of a given pixel.
{
    float Blue = 0;
    float Green = 0;
    float Red = 0;

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
        {
            // for rows and columns out of range.
            if ((i + row) < 0 || (i + row >= height) || (j + col) < 0 || (j + col >= width))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // for (-1,-1) and (-1,1)
            else if ((i == -1 && j == -1) || (i == -1 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -1;
            }

            // for (0, -1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == -1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * -2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * -2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * -2;
            }

            // for (0, -1) , (0, 0), (0, 1)
            else if ((i == 0 && j == -1) || (i == 0 && j == 0) || (i == 0 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 0;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 0;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 0;
            }

            // for (1, 0)
            else if ((i ==1 && j == 0))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 2;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 2;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 2;
            }

            // for (1,-1) and (1,1)
            else if ((i == 1 && j == -1) || (i == 1 && j == 1))
            {
                Blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue * 1;
                Green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen * 1;
                Red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed * 1;
            }
        }
    }

    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtBlue = fabsf(Blue);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtGreen = fabsf(Green);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtRed = fabsf(Red);
}
```

r_sqrt_sum function:

```
int r_sqrt_sum(float a, float b)
// Return rounded sqrt of sum of squared a and b.
{
    float x = round(sqrt((a*a + b*b)));

    if (x > 255) return 255;

    else return x;
}
```

Comment: and *how* does it not match with the answer? show inputs and outputs. [edit] your question. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think there is some bug in the code that's why the pixels shown in the answer are quite different than obtained in  output. As observed there is no other figure ouatable pattern between answer and the output pixels, which will help in solving the problem correctly. I think the sobel operator is not applied correctly here, but can't figure out what is the mistake.

Comment: don't assume that people will compile and run your code. show what needs to be shown. that means show inputs and outputs.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Bro I have given all the relevant information required for the problem and for someone to find the bug in my code.